# Run multiple lines from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get a bat file together and not sure how to run multiple cmd lines through the .bat.

Objective: I want to be able to click on this .bat file to open cmd prompt, then to find a "folder" in the directory, rename the "Folder"  then move the location of the folder then find a existing Folder and put it in the same directory.

Problem: i know how to run these cmds in the prompt without an issues.

So far this is what i have:

```
@echo off 
start cmd.exe /k cd %AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question

Comment: A batch file is simply a text file with a `.bat`, _(or better `.cmd`)_, extension which contains each of the commands you've been running at the Command Prompt, one per line.

Comment: When you click on a .bat file, Windows already opens a `cmd` window. No need to do it again.

Answer (score -1):

@echo off

and then just write your commands its that simple

Comment: you can also rename it .cmd or .com

Comment: they let you silently run the batch file

Comment: hope ii was helpful

Answer (score -2):

A .bat file is executed in a terminal window automatically, you don't need to call cmd.exe or anything like that.

Every single line you write in the .bat file is going to be executed one by one, so you just need to write multiple lines with all the instructions and then you can double click on your new file to run the script.

If you are not familiar with Windows commands for the terminal, you can find more info on the web about how to find a folder, rename it, etc. There are many things you can do by command line and this is not the right place to explain how to use them.